# Resetting ip address gives "media disconnected" error message

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip-address

I am using my windows 8 laptop and I am successfully connected to my router and can access my internet with no problem. I want to get a new ip address. I opened up the command prompt and then typed in

```
ipconfig /renew
```

and it gave me an error message saying

```
Windows IP Configuration
No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection* 15 while it has its media disconnected.
No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection* 14 while it has its media disconnected.
No operation can be performed on Ethernet while it has its media disconnected.

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 15:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 14:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : gateway.2wire.net
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8595:65a1:23db:b3e4%13
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.37
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.gateway.2wire.net:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : gateway.2wire.net

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 13:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Any idea why it is giving this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no error there.

> No operation can be performed on Ethernet while it has its media disconnected.

Those lines at the top are just telling you it can't renew the IP address for adapters that are unplugged and/or disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

There's no error. You have 4 physical network adapters in the computer, 3 of which are disconnected. You can't acquire or renew an ip address for a NIC that isn't connected.